# How to update many documents in mongodb using golang

Tags: mongodb, go

While reading the update many records [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/). There is mongodb shell query which is used to update many records in the db. Then I want to implement below given query in the golang for update many documents. I also check the [mgo](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Bulk.UpdateAll) document There is a function which update many documents But it will take only two parameters first is `selector` and other one is the `update`. But in the mongodb [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) there are three parameters we have to pass in the query. In the collection there are 200k records and I have only update the 2000 records. I want to implement the below query in the golang:

```
db.collection.update(
 <query>,
 <update>,
 {
   upsert: <boolean>,
   multi: <boolean>,
   writeConcern: <document>,
   collation: <document>,
   arrayFilters: [ <filterdocument1>, ... ]
  }
)
```

I used it like this:

```
UpdateAll(config.BookingsCollection, nil, bson.M{"$set": bson.M{"is_price_field": 1}}).Limit(2000)
```

It will gives me the error:

> multiple-value UpdateAll() in single-value context

When I remove the Limit(2000) then it will show no error but it will not satisfy my result.

**Updated**

Basically I'm following the MVC structure

Controllers:

```
func BulkUpdateBookings(c *gin.Context) {
 err := models.UpdateBulkBookingsDb()
 fmt.Println(err)
}
```

Models:

```
func UpdateBulkBookingsDb() (err error) {
  mongoSession := config.ConnectDb()// database connection
  defer mongoSession.Close()
  sessionCopy := mongoSession.Copy()
  defer sessionCopy.Close()
  getCollection := sessionCopy.DB(Database).C(collection)
   _, err = getCollection.UpdateAll(nil, bson.M{"$set": bson.M{"is_price_update": 0}})
  return err
}
```

Comment: can you please give us more codes? or near-complete code? because the `DbUpdateAll` function is not from mgo

Comment: @xpare see the update

Comment: @ansh as you cant add a limit on update /updateMany or update with multi True

Comment: @vipul is there is any method in golang which is used to update the documents in the given limit

Comment: no there isnt any such method. If you have criteria then you add use that
eg. db.users.update({"_id:{$in:[1,2,4,5,6,]}},{update value});